# Simple Nodejs Regex: Extract text from between two strings

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm trying to extract the Vine ID from the following URL:

```
https://vine.co/v/Mipm1LMKVqJ/embed
```

I'm using this regex:

```
/v/(.*)/
```

and testing it here: http://regexpal.com/

...but it's matching the V and closing "/". How can I just get "Mipm1LMKVqJ", and what would be the cleanest way to do this in Node?

Comment: Although you should not use regex, it works fine and you need to reference group index 1 to get the match result.

Comment: As for your regex, you should make the `*` non greedy, so `(.*?)`. And like hwnd said, grab the sub-group.

Comment: `s = s.slice(s.indexOf("/v/") + 3); s.slice(0, s.indexOf("/"));` I had my indices mixed up on the first version.

Comment: It is not a nodejs regex, there is no such thing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to reference the first match group in order to print the match result only.

```
var re = new RegExp('/v/(.*)/');
var r  = 'https://vine.co/v/Mipm1LMKVqJ/embed'.match(re);
if (r)
    console.log(r[1]); //=> "Mipm1LMKVqJ"
```

**Note:** If the url often change, I recommend using `*?` to prevent greediness in your match.

Although from the following url, maybe consider splitting.

```
var r = 'https://vine.co/v/Mipm1LMKVqJ/embed'.split('/')[4]
console.log(r); //=> "Mipm1LMKVqJ"
```